# Arduino clock event

Tags: loops, arduino, frequency

I'm currently programming curie nano v2.0 arduino board. And I need to call a function at a rate of 250hz. One way of doing it simply put a delay of 3 or 4 milliseconds to get approximation of 250hz.

Is there a library or some clock event that can trigger every 4ms sending an event and thus running the function I need or any other smart method without using the delay() function.

One way of doing it would be to make an eventEmitter which constantly probes the clock and asks for the time and if desired timeframe has passed, send an event. But I suspect that this method would be computationally heavy, always probing the clock. Can someone help?

Comment: Please see my answer below which requires no additional library and therefore probably more compact code size.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `CurieTimerOne` library for this and its method `CurieTimerOne.start(int timerPeriodUsec, userCallBack)`.

Here is the sample code:

```
#include "CurieTimerOne.h"

bool ledState = false;
#define LED_PIN 13

// callback which toggles the LED
void blinkProc()   
{
  digitalWrite(LED_PIN, ledState);
  ledState = !ledState;  // change state.
}

void setup()
{
    pinMode(LED_PIN, OUTPUT);
    // 4000us is 4ms or 250Hz.
    CurieTimerOne.start(4000, blinkProc);
}

void loop()
{
    // do other stuff.
}
```

What is good with using timers(interrupts) is that your function will be called at exact frequency you want, which is not possible with `delay()`.

[Reference to CurieTimeOne libary at official Arduino website](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/CurieTimerOne)

Answer (score 0):

You could add an interrupt to the timer that's already running for `millis()`, which incurs very low overhead.  Here's an interrupt-based example that lets your code do other things except when the 4ms timer has elapsed.  This has the benefit of no additional libraries needed, smaller code size.  It's also a small introduction to interrupts at the hardware level if you've never explored that before.

```
volatile uint8_t reduce4 = 0;      // used to get 4 ms
volatile uint8_t timerAlert = LOW; // flag that tells you 4ms is up

void setup() {
  pinMode(12, OUTPUT);    // an output pin just for testing on my oscilloscope
  OCR0A = 0xAF;           // set up interrupt
  TIMSK0 |= _BV(OCIE0A);
}

SIGNAL(TIMER0_COMPA_vect) // interrupt handler
{
  reduce4++;
  if (reduce4 == 4)
  {
    timerAlert = HIGH;   // only fire every 4th time
    reduce4 = 0;
  }
}

void loop()
{
  if (timerAlert == HIGH)
  {
    digitalWrite(12, !digitalRead(12));
    // DO OTHER STUFF
    timerAlert = LOW;
  }
}
```

Comment: Im getting this error. 
sketch_jul14b:4: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘(’ token
 SIGNAL(TIMER0_COMPA_vect) // interrupt handler
       ^
exit status 1
expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘(’ token

Comment: @user3630461  I just edited, pasted directly from running sketch.